# How to use PayPal API for total order quantity discounts

Tags: paypal

I've taken over updating my choral society's web page temporarily and need to make a change in our use of the PayPal API. Here's what I need to accomplish.

We want to sell concert tickets for $20 (adult) and $10(student) in qty 1-2. For qty 3 and above in any combinations of adult and/or student. the price should be $16.50 (adult) and $8.25 (student).

```
Examples (just to be absolutely clear):
1 adult ticket : $20
2 adult tickets: $40
3 adult tickets: $49.50
4 adult tickets: $66
etc ...

1 student ticket: $10
2 student tickets: $20
3 student tickets $24.75
4 student tickets: $33
etc ...

1 adult + 1 student: $30
1 adult + 2 student: $33
2 adult + 1 student: $41.25
etc ...
```

Previously, our website had Add To Cart buttons for various combinations. It's confusing to customers and unreliable, too, since PayPal provides its own form where quantities can be changed.

I want to replace all of our current Add to Cart buttons with a single Buy Now button that leads to a page where the customer can specify any mix of quantities of adult and student tickets (as long as both are not zero) and proceed to payment with the pricing described above.

I've looked at the [PayPal API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HF080O3%20%22PayPal%20API) and see several fields (in Table 3) relating to discounting, but it's not at all clear whether there's a combination that will do what I want.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from PayPal Support and lots of googling for sample code, I've come up with the following which seems to be working satisfactorily in beta.  The keydown logic came from another question on StackOverflow.

The code creates a pair of text boxes for Adult and Student quantities.  The discounting rules are enforced as customers enter quantities to display a subtotal string above the inputs.  When the customer clicks "Buy Now",  the total is sent as a single item to create the payment form. An S&H fee is also added as a percent of the total to cover transaction costs.

Apologies for the verbose coding style.  JavaScript is not my usual language. Suggestions for improvement welcome.

Hope someone finds it useful!

WARNING -- THIS CODE IS VULNERABLE TO CHEATING BY CROOKS WITH COMPUTER SKILLS.  DON'T USE IT FOR VALUABLE TRANSACTIONS WITHOUT SOME FORM OF POST-PURCHASE AUDIT.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Enforce numeric values only. 
    $('#nadult, #nstudent').keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
        }
    });
    $('#nadult, #nstudent').keyup(function(event) {
        compute_form_inputs(false);
        });
  });

  function compute_form_inputs(is_submit) {
      // called when buyer click "Buy now" after filling in quantities of adult and student tickets
      var base_adult_price = 20.00;
      var disc_adult_price = 16.50;
      var student_discount = 0.50;
      var handling_fee = 0.05 // Five percent to cover cost of transaction;
      var nadult = $('#nadult').val();
      var nstudent = $('#nstudent').val();
      var iadult = parseInt(nadult);
      if (isNaN(iadult)) { iadult = 0 }
      var istudent = parseInt(nstudent);
      if (isNaN(istudent)) { istudent = 0 }
      var itickets = istudent + iadult;

      if (is_submit && itickets <= 0) { 
          // call off the purchase 
          alert("Please specify at least one adult or student ticket to purchase!");
          return false; 
          } 
      else if (itickets < 3) {
          var adult_price = base_adult_price;
      } 
      else {
          var adult_price = disc_adult_price;
      }

      var student_price = adult_price * student_discount;

      // Build string components that show how many of each were purchased.
      // These go into the PayPal item_name field.
      if (iadult > 0) {
          var adult_info = nadult + " Adult @ $" + adult_price.toFixed(2) + " ea.";
      }
      else {
          var adult_info = "";
      }

      if (istudent > 0) {
          var student_info = nstudent + " Student @ $" + student_price.toFixed(2) +"ea.";
      }
      else {
          var student_info = "";
      }

      if (iadult>0 && istudent>0) {
          var separator = " + ";
      }
      else {
          var separator = "";
      }


      var item_name_string = "ACS Flex tickets: " + adult_info + separator + student_info;
      var amount = iadult * adult_price + istudent * student_price;
      //alert(amount);
      var handling = (amount * handling_fee).toFixed(2);


      //alert(handling);
      $('input[name="item_name"]').val(item_name_string);
      $('input[name="amount"]').val(amount);
      $('input[name="handling"]').val(handling);
      $('input[name="custom"]').val(item_name_string);
      // alert("about to change label")
      $('#subtotal').text(adult_info + separator + student_info + " = $" + amount.toFixed(2))
      return true;
  };  

// ]]></script>


<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit=compute_form_inputs(true) method="post">
<div style="color: green; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<strong>Subtotal:&nbsp;<label id="subtotal" value=""></strong><super>*</super><br />
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" id="nadult" value="0" size="3"> <strong> Adult </strong>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="nstudent" value="0" size="3"> <strong> Student </strong>&nbsp;
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="someone@mychoralsociety.org">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="handling" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</div>
</form>  
<br /> 
<small> * 5% transaction fee will be  added to online and credit card purchase to cover bank fees. </small>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your button code. The discount rate is in percentage which is 17.5%. The first line with zero in it is added so that the discount does not apply to the first item.

```
<input type="hidden" name="discount_rate" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="discount_rate2" value="17.5">
```

Or if your button is PayPal hosted add these to advanced variables in 3rd section

```
discount_rate=0
discount_rate2=17.5
```

Source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/